# R - combining columns by specific conditions

Tags: r

I currently has a data frame as follow:

```
groups <- data.frame(name=paste("person",c(1:27),sep=""), 
assignment1 = c("F","A","B","H", "A", "E", "D", "G", "I", "I", "E", "A", "D", "C", "F", "C", "D", "H", "F", "H", "G", "I", "G", "C", "B", "E", "B"),
assignment2 = c("H", "F", "F", "D", "E", "G", "A", "E", "I", "C", "A", "H", "G", "B", "I", "C", "E", "I", "C", "A", "B", "B", "G", "D", "H", "F", "D"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

It would looks like this:
[image]

I would like to create a list for each person that only contains the people he had already worked with. For example, person1 is on **group F and H** for **1st and 2nd assignment** respectively and

The member of **groups F on 1st assignment** are **{"person1","person15", "person19"}**. 

The member of **groups D on 2nd assignment** are **{"person1","person12", "person25"}**.

I would like to create a vector for person1 like

**{"person15", "person19", "person12", "person25"}**.

Any one knows a convenient way to do this in R? 

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be you should check the `library(igraph)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
teammates <- lapply(1:nrow(groups), function(i) {
  assig1 <- subset(groups, assignment1 == groups$assignment1[i])$name
  assig2 <- subset(groups, assignment2 == groups$assignment2[i])$name
  unq_set <- unique(c(assig1, assig2))
  return(setdiff(unq_set, groups$name[i]))
})
```

This takes a vector of row indices, and for each one applies a function that a) gets the `name`s of those where assignments 1 & 2 match the given row, b) gets the unique superset of these, c) returns that, less the `name` of the person around whom the group is built

The output is a list like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "person15" "person19" "person12" "person25"

[[2]]
[1] "person5"  "person12" "person3"  "person26"

[[3]]
[1] "person25" "person27" "person2"  "person26"
```

...and so on

For more brevity, the following is equivalent (though order inside list items may be different). Same logic as @user5219763's answer for subsetting, but the setdiff part is important

```
teammates <- lapply(1:nrow(groups), function(i) {
  setdiff(
    with(groups, name[assignment1 == assignment1[i] |
                      assignment2 == assignment2[i] ]),
    groups$name[i])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using dplyr and tidyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
groups %>%
  gather(var, val, -name) %>%
  unite(comb, var, val) %>%
  left_join(.,., by = 'comb') %>%
  group_by(name.x) %>%
  summarise(out = list(name.y))
```

The heavy lifting is done using the `left_join` before that we are combining columns, so that we can merge on eg `assignment1_f`. The output contains itself, and is not corrected for dupes - that is up to you.

However, as @akrun says, if you are doing a lot of this stuff, use `igraph`

Answer (score -1):

You could use `is.element()`

```
workedWith <- function(index,data=groups){
    data[is.element(data[,2],data[index,2]) | is.element(data[,3],data[index,3]),1]
}

lapply(X = seq(1:nrow(groups)),FUN = workedWith)
```

Comment: This only works for one person. Can we separate all the 27 person at one time ?

Comment: I edited my answer to work for all rows. As others have pointed out you can achieve the same result with twice the amount of code and a few extra packages.